# How do I limit an SAML IDP to a certain group of users in django?

Tags: python, django, saml, saml-2.0

I'm trying to get my head around some SAML concepts. We are implementing SAML support in our django-based SaaS. According to my understanding, I have to implement a SAML Service Provider. There are ways to do this using, eg djangosaml2. Using djangosaml2 I can also map SAML user attributes to django user attributes.

What I want to do, that I have so far not found how, is to limit a certain IDP to a certain group of users, so that I can map one IDP to one customer and only allow that IDP to log in as users belonging to that customer account. I'm guessing this should be a fairly standard setup and I'm missing something obvious, but what? How do I limit an IDP to be able to authenticate only a certain group of users?

Comment: Can you limit the IdPs from which you are choosing, as you say, and then on your SP side accept only responses with the predetermined groups (entitlements), else reject the validation?